# Why const keyword is used after assignment operator in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning Flutter(Mostly from Youtube) & while learning it I have seen many instructor have used a statement like this,

```
final SomeClass someVariable = const SomeClass(withSomeValue);
```

What bothers me that why do we need to use `const` keyword after the assignment operator there since we already made it a `final` & I already know that `final` keyword is used to define a constant variable. So what does `const` signifies here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a memory optimization possible with immutable objects.

`const` instances are shared:

```dart
final a = const Whatever();
final b = const Whatever();

print(identical(a, b)); // true
```

In this snippet, both `a` and `b` share the same object instance, so it is allocated only once.

Answer (score 3):

Here, the object allocation, takes place just once, so it is good for performance.

```
final Test test = const Test();
final Test test2 = const Test();
```

Here it takes place twice.

```
final Test test = Test();
final Test test2 = Test();
```